# New line in the text box

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I'm the Inter-key in textBox.But the new line will not.What do I need.

Whether there is a solution ?

Comment: Inter pressing in the textbox And go to new line.

Comment: @sll : I need to Multi-line text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<TextBox
  Name="tbMultiLine"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  AcceptsReturn="True"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
>
  This TextBox will allow the user to enter multiple lines of text.  When the RETURN key is pressed, 
  or when typed text reaches the edge of the text box, a new line is automatically inserted.
</TextBox
```

See [How to: Create a Multiline TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742157.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Textblock and set the following parameters in your XAML:

```
<TextBox name="textBox1"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    AcceptsReturn="true"/>
```